what additions should be made to this text file with helpful symfony husky
Symfony Installation:
Created a Symfony project using Composer with the symfony/skeleton package.
Added the webapp package using Composer.



composer create-project symfony/skeleton:"7.0.*" symfony_test_app
composer require webapp

Database Setup:
Configured the database URL with credentials.
Created the database schema using Symfony's Doctrine commands.

DATABASE_URL="mysql://username:password@host:port/database_name?serverVersion=10.4.28-MariaDB&charset=utf8mb4"
php ./bin/console doctrine:database:create
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
Symfony Packages Installation:
Installed essential Symfony packages like symfony/orm-pack, symfony/form, symfony/maker-bundle, and symfony/framework-bundle.
Generated migrations, entities, forms, user authentication, etc., using Symfony's console commands.

composer require symfony/orm-pack
composer require symfony/form
composer require symfony/maker-bundle --dev
composer require symfony/framework-bundle
php bin/console make:migration
php bin/console make:entity
php bin/console make:form PersonType Person
php bin/console make:user
php bin/console make:auth

Front-end Dependencies:
Included Bootstrap and jQuery CDN links for styling and client-side scripting.

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Front-end Script:
Added JavaScript code to filter items based on categories using Bootstrap's button groups.

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".filter-button").click(function(){
            var value = $(this).attr('data-filter');

            if(value === "all") {
                $('.filter').show('1000');
            } else {
                $(".filter").not('.'+value).hide('slow');
                $('.filter').filter('.'+value).show('slow');
            }

            $(".filter-button").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
        });
    });
</script>


Symfony Controller:
Created a Symfony controller named RegistrierungController for handling user registration.
Defined a route /registrierung for accessing the registration form.

<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RepeatedType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\PasswordHasher\Hasher\UserPasswordHasherInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class RegistrierungController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/registrierung', name: 'app_registrierung')]
    public function reg(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, UserPasswordHasherInterface $passwordHasher): Response
    {
        // Form handling logic here...
    }
}

Twig Template:
Utilized Twig templating engine to render the registration form.
Extended the base template to maintain consistency across pages.
Rendered the registration form using Symfony's form rendering functions.

twig

{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Hello RegistrierungController!{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

<h1>RegistrierungController</h1>

{{ form_start(regform) }}
{{ form_widget(regform) }}
{{ form_end(regform) }}

{% endblock %}


Front-end Component:
Implemented a carousel component using Bootstrap's Carousel to display car details.
Dynamically populated car details using Twig's loop syntax.
Linked each carousel item to a detailed view page using Symfony's routing system.

<section>
    <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            {% for car in cars %}
                <div class="carousel-item {% if loop.first %}active{% endif %}">
                    <h2>{{ car.getModel() }}</h2>
                    <img class="carousel-image" src="{{ asset('images/' ~ car.getImage()) }}" alt="{{ car.getBrand() }}">
                    <br>
                    <a class="details-button" href="{{ path('car_details', {'id': car.getId()}) }}">Click here for more details</a>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</section>


This setup provides a comprehensive guide for setting up a Symfony application with user registration and front-end components like filtering buttons and carousels for displaying data.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

here would be the register controller logic

<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RepeatedType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\PasswordHasher\Hasher\UserPasswordHasherInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Attribute\Route;

class RegistrierungController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/registrierung', name: 'app_registrierung')]
    public function reg(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, UserPasswordHasherInterface $passwordHasher): Response
    {

        $regform = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->add('username', TextType::class, ['label' => 'Mitarbeiter'])
            ->add('password', RepeatedType::class, [
                'type' => PasswordType::class,
                'required'=> true,
                'first_options' => ['label' => 'Passwort'],
                'second_options' => ['label'=> 'Passwort wiederholen']
            ])
            ->add('registrieren', SubmitType::class)
            ->getForm();

        $regform->handleRequest($request);

        //wurde der Submit-Button gedrückt!
        if($regform->isSubmitted() && $regform->isValid()){
            $eingabe  = $regform->getData();
            dump($eingabe);

            $user = new User();
            $user->setUsername(($eingabe['username']));
            $user->setPassword($passwordHasher->hashPassword($user, $eingabe['password']));

            $entityManager->persist($user);
            $entityManager->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('car_home'));
        }


        return $this->render('registrierung/index.html.twig', [
            'regform' => $regform->createView(),
        ]);
    }
}




        Dropdown
    

Action
Another action

Something else here


form_theme: 'bootstrap_5_layout.html.twig'
twig.yaml


    
        Dropdown
    
    
        Action
        Another action
        
        Something else here
    


image_folder: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/images/'
services.yaml

How to make the pictures displayed:
Im Type --> bei bild -->  
, FileType:class, ['mapped' => false])

Controller --> 
$bild = $request->files->get('car')['bild'];
        if ($bild) {
            $dateiname = md5(uniqid()) . '.' . $bild->guessClientExtension();
        }
        $bild->move(
            $this->getParameter('bilder_ordner'), $dateiname
        );
        $car->setBild($dateiname);


services.yaml -->
parameters:
    bilder_ordner: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/bilder/'


Something more for the register controller:
In der index.html.twig
delete the stuff in the div and add the following:
<h2>Regestrierung</h2>

{{ form(regform) }}

Jetzt einen beliebigen User erstellen und sehen, ob er in der DB gespeichert wird
In CustemAuthenticator
In the Function: onAuthenticationSuccess
The Row with „throw“ comment out and in the following to paste:
return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('gericht.index'));

security.yaml
In the file “config/packages/security.yaml” the folliwing to paste in:
At the subpoint „firewall“:
logout:
    path: app_logout
    target: app_login

And at the extra subpoint
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
    - { path: ^/gericht, roles: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/reg, roles: ROLE_USER }

A Menu for public and one only for logged in User

#[Route('/car/new', name: 'car_new', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
public function new(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
{
    $car = new Car();
    $form = $this->createForm(CarType::class, $car);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $image = $form->get('image')->getData();

        if ($image) {
            $filename = md5(uniqid()) . '.' . $image->guessExtension();
            $image->move(
                $this->getParameter('image_folder'),
                $filename
            );
            $car->setImage($filename);
        }
        $entityManager->persist($car);
        $entityManager->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('car_new');
    }

    return $this->render('car/index.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}

for picture

I think you should consider using the following additions to your applications.yaml:
spring.application.name=gibmirhoffnung
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:gibmirhoffnung
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=test
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.shell.interactive.enabled=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.sql.init.mode=always

If you consider these it should work fine

i think you should consider the jpql query and native query in the studentrepository.java
// JPQL: Find students by age greater than a specific value
    @Query("SELECT s FROM Student s WHERE s.age > ?1")
    List<Student> getStudentsByAgeGreaterThan(int age);

// JPQL: Get first names of students by age greater than a specific value
@Query("SELECT s.firstName FROM Student s WHERE s.age > ?1")
List<String> getFirstNameByAgeGreaterThan(int age);

// Native SQL: Find students with age between two values
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM student s WHERE s.age BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2", nativeQuery = true)
List<Student> getStudentsByAgeBetween(int age1, int age2);

// Native SQL: Find students with age between a minimum and maximum value using named parameters
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM student s WHERE s.age BETWEEN :minAge AND :maxAge", nativeQuery = true)
List<Student> getStudentByAgeBetweenMinAndMaxAge(@Param("minAge") int minAge, @Param("maxAge") int maxAge);

not to forget the studentrepository test. java
the student repository test also helps with junit testing
package RepositoryTest;


import model.Student;
import repository.StudentRepository;
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.EmbeddedDatabaseConnection;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.AutoConfigureTestDatabase;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(connection = EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.H2)
public class StudentRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository studentRepository;

    @Test
    public void StudentRepository_SaveStudent_ReturnSavedStudent(){


        Student student = Student.builder()
                .firstName("Joe")
                .lastName("Doe")
                .build();

        Student savedStudent = studentRepository.save(student);

        Assertions.assertThat(savedStudent).isNotNull();
        Assertions.assertThat(savedStudent.getFirstName().equals("Joe"));

    }

    @Test
    public void StudentRepository_StudetsByAgeGreaterThan_ReturnStudent(){

        Student student = Student.builder()
                .firstName("Joe")
                .lastName("Doe")
                .age(20)
                .build();

        Student student2 = Student.builder()
                .firstName("Joe")
                .lastName("Doe")
                .age(19)
                .build();

        studentRepository.save(student);
        studentRepository.save(student2);

List<Student> savedStudent =studentRepository.getStudentsByAgeGreaterThan(10);

Assertions.assertThat(savedStudent).isNotNull();
Assertions.assertThat(savedStudent.size()).isEqualTo(2);

    }


    @Test
    public void StudentRepository_GetAll_ReturnMoreThanOneStudent(){

        Student student = Student.builder()
                .firstName("Joe")
                .lastName("Doe")
                .age(20)
                .build();

        Student student2 = Student.builder()
                .firstName("Joe")
                .lastName("Doe")
                .age(19)
                .build();

        studentRepository.save(student);
        studentRepository.save(student2);

        List<Student> savedStudent = studentRepository.findAll();

        Assertions.assertThat(savedStudent).isNotNull();
        Assertions.assertThat(savedStudent.size()).isEqualTo(2);


    }

    @Test
    public void StudentRepository_FindById_ReturnStudent(){
        Student student = Student.builder()
                .id(1)
                .firstName("Joe")
                .lastName("Doe")
                .age(20)
                .build();

Student savedStudent = studentRepository.save(student);

Student studentById = studentRepository.findById(savedStudent.getId()).orElse(null);

    Assertions.assertThat(studentById).isNotNull();

    Assertions.assertThat(studentById.getId()).isEqualTo(savedStudent.getId());


    }

    @Test
    public void StudentRepository_FindByAgeGreater_ReturnStudents(){

        Student student = Student.builder()

                .firstName("Joe")
                .lastName("Doe")
                .age(20)
                .build();

        Student student2 = Student.builder()

                .firstName("Joe")
                .lastName("Doe")
                .age(10)
                .build();

        studentRepository.save(student);
        studentRepository.save(student2);

        List<Student> savedStudent = studentRepository.getStudentsByAgeGreaterThan(5);

        Assertions.assertThat(savedStudent).isNotNull();
        Assertions.assertThat(savedStudent.size()).isEqualTo(2);
    }





    }

of course you can add the student service to your project
    import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@AllArgsConstructor
@Service
public class StudentService {

@Autowired
private StudentRepository studentRepository;



public Student create(Student student){
    return studentRepository.save(student);
}

public Student updateStudent(Student student, int id){
    Student stud =  studentRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    stud.setFirstName(student.getFirstName());
    stud.setLastName(student.getLastName());

    return studentRepository.save(stud);
}

public List<Student> getAllStudents(){
    return studentRepository.findAll();
}

public void removeStudent(Integer id){
        studentRepository.deleteById(id);

    }

    public Student getStudentById(Integer id){
        return studentRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }

public Page<Student> getPagedStudents() {
    Pageable sortedByName = PageRequest.of(0, 3, Sort.by("firstName").descending());
    return studentRepository.findAll(sortedByName);
}

}
StudentServiceTest:
    package ServiceTest;

import model.Student;
import repository.StudentRepository;
import service.StudentService;
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

import java.util.Optional;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;


@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class StudentServiceTest {

    // Mock object of StudentRepository
    @Mock
    private StudentRepository studentRepository;


    @InjectMocks
    private StudentService studentService;

    @Test
    public void StudentService_CreateStudent_ReturnStudent() {

        Student student = Student.builder()
                .firstName("Joe")
                .lastName("Doe")
                .build();


        when(studentRepository.save(Mockito.any(Student.class))).thenReturn(student);

        Student savedStudent = studentService.create(student);

        Assertions.assertThat(savedStudent).isNotNull();
        Assertions.assertThat(savedStudent.getFirstName()).isEqualTo(student.getFirstName());

    }

@Test
    public void StudentService_GetById_ReturnStudent(){

        Student student = Student.builder()
                .firstName("Joe")
                .lastName("Doe")
                .age(19)
                .build();


        when(studentRepository.findById(1)).thenReturn(Optional.ofNullable(student));
        when(studentRepository.findById(2)).thenReturn(Optional.empty());

        Student savedStudentId = studentService.getStudentById(1);
        Assertions.assertThat(savedStudentId).isNotNull();

        Student savedStudentId2 = studentService.getStudentById(2);
        Assertions.assertThat(savedStudentId2).isNull();
    }

    @Test
    public void StudentService_UpdateStudent_ReturnUpdatedStudent(){

        Student student1 = Student.builder()
                .firstName("Joe")
                .lastName("Doe")
                .build();

        when(studentRepository.save(Mockito.any(Student.class))).thenReturn(student1);
        when(studentRepository.findById(1)).thenReturn(Optional.ofNullable(student1));

        Student updatedStudent = studentService.updateStudent(student1, 1);

        Assertions.assertThat(updatedStudent).isNotNull();
        Assertions.assertThat(updatedStudent.getFirstName()).isEqualTo(student1.getFirstName());




    }
}

additionally the pom.xml is very important
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>productApplication</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>productApplication</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.shell</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-shell-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

the student entity
import lombok.*;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "student")

@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "student_id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "age")
    private Integer age;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(
            name = "student_course",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "course_id")
    )
    private List<Course> courses = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Course> getCourses() {
        return courses;
    }

    public void setCourses(List<Course> courses) {
        this.courses = courses;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}

the teacher entity
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "teacher")

public class Teacher {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "teacher_id")
    private Integer id;


    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "teacher",orphanRemoval = true,  cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.PERSIST}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Course> courses;

    public Set<Course> getCourses() {
        return courses;
    }

    public void setCourses(Set<Course> courses) {
        this.courses = courses;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
}

the course entity
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "course")
public class Course {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "course_id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;


    @Column (name = "abbreviation")
    private String abbreviation;



    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "courses", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();






    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinColumn(name = "teacher_id")
    private Teacher teacher;

    public List<Student> getStudents() {
        return students;
    }

    public void setStudents(List<Student> students) {
        this.students = students;
    }

    public Teacher getTeacher() {
        return teacher;
    }

    public void setTeacher(Teacher teacher) {
        this.teacher = teacher;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAbbreviation() {
        return abbreviation;
    }

    public void setAbbreviation(String abbreviation) {
        this.abbreviation = abbreviation;
    }
}

studentcontroller
import model.Student;
import service.StudentService;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;


@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@RestController
public class StudentController {

    @Autowired
    private StudentService studentService;

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello World";
    }

    @PostMapping("/students")
    public Student createStudent(@RequestBody Student student) {
        return studentService.create(student);
    }

    @GetMapping("/findAll")
    public List<Student> get(){
      return studentService.getAllStudents();
    }

@GetMapping("/students/{id}")
    public Student getById(@PathVariable Integer id){
        Student student = studentService.getStudentById(id);
        if (student == null){
            return null;
        }
        return student;
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/students/{id}")
    public void deleteStudent(@PathVariable Integer id){
        studentService.removeStudent(id);

    }

    @GetMapping("/students/paged")
    public Page<Student> getPagedStudents() {
        return studentService.getPagedStudents();
    }


}

the http.request
    ###
GET localhost:8080/hello

###
POST http://localhost:8080/students
Content-Type: application/json

{


  "firstName": "Joe",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "age": 19,
  "courses": [
    {
      "name": "Math",
      "abbreviation": "MTH"
    }
  ]
}

###
POST http://localhost:8080/students
Content-Type: application/json

{

  "firstName": "Mia",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "age": 21,
    "courses": [
        {
        "name": "Softwaare Engineering",
        "abbreviation": "SE"
        }

    ]
}

###
POST http://localhost:8080/students
Content-Type: application/json

{

  "firstName": "Harry",
  "lastName": "Potter",
  "age": 14,
  "courses": [
    {
      "name": "History",
      "abbreviation": "HIS"
    }
  ]
}

###
POST http://localhost:8080/teachers
Content-Type: application/json

{

  "firstName": "John",
  "courses": [
    {
      "name": "English",
        "abbreviation": "ENG"
    }
  ]
}

###
GET http://localhost:8080/findAll


###
GET http://localhost:8080/students/paged

Lambda-Funktionen in Java sind anonyme Funktionen, also Funktionen ohne Namen, die direkt verwendet werden können. Sie ermöglichen es, kurze und prägnante Codeabschnitte zu schreiben, insbesondere bei der Arbeit mit funktionalen Schnittstellen wie Runnable, Comparator oder der Stream-API.
Einfach gesagt, Lambda-Funktionen erlauben es, Verhalten (also Code) als Daten zu behandeln und an Methoden oder Objekte zu übergeben.
Shape
Beispiel ohne Lambda:
Ohne Lambda-Ausdrücke müssen wir oft anonyme Klassen verwenden:
   Runnable runnable = new Runnable() { 
    @Override 
    public void run() { 
        System.out.println("Hello, World!"); 
    } 
}; 
runnable.run(); 

Das gleiche Beispiel mit Lambda:
Mit einer Lambda-Funktion wird der Code viel kompakter:
    Runnable runnable = () -> System.out.println("Hello, World!"); 
runnable.run(); 

Die Syntax einer Lambda-Funktion besteht aus drei Teilen:
Parameterliste: (x, y) – die Eingabeparameter.
Pfeil-Operator: -> – trennt die Parameter von der Funktion.
Funktionskörper: { x + y } – der eigentliche Code.
Lambda-Funktionen wurden in Java mit Version 8 eingeführt. Sie sind möglich, weil Java durch mehrere technische und konzeptionelle Änderungen auf Lambda-Funktionen vorbereitet wurde:
Funktionale Schnittstellen
Java unterstützt Lambda-Funktionen, weil es funktionale Schnittstellen gibt.
Eine funktionale Schnittstelle ist ein Interface, das genau eine abstrakte Methode enthält, wie z. B. Runnable oder Comparator.
Lambda-Funktionen bieten eine kompakte Möglichkeit, diese abstrakte Methode zu implementieren.
Lambda Beispiel ArrayList print loop
public class Main { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
        numbers.add(5); 
        numbers.add(9); 
        numbers.add(8); 
        numbers.add(1); 
        numbers.forEach( (n) -> { System.out.println(n); } ); 
    } 
} 

Lambda Beispiel sortierung nachname aufsteigend:
    personList.sort((Person o1, Person o2) -> 
        o1.getNachname().compareTo(o2.getNachname())); 
System.out.println("Sorted List by Nachname:"); 
for (Person person : personList) { 
    person.getPesonData(); 
}

PhotozController.java:
    @PostMapping("/photoz") 
public Photo create(@RequestPart("data") MultipartFile file) throws IOException { 
 
 
    returnphotozService.save(file.getOriginalFilename(),file.getContentType(), file.getBytes()); 
} 

PhotozService.java:
        public Photo save(String fileName, String contentType, byte[] data) { 
        Photo photo = new Photo(); 
        photo.setContentType(contentType); 
    photo.setFileName(fileName); 
    photo.setData(data); 
photozRepository.save(photo); 
return photo; 
    } 

upload.html
<body> 
<h2>Photo Upload</h2> 
 
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="fileupload" /> 
<button id="upload-button" onclick="uploadFile()"> Upload </button> 
 
<script> 
    async function uploadFile() { 
        let formData = new FormData(); 
        formData.append("data", fileupload.files[0]); 
        await fetch('http://localhost:8080/photoz', { 
            method: "POST", 
            body: formData 
        }).then(result =>    result.text()) 
            .then(text => alert(text)); 
    } 
</script> 
</body> 

spring shell
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.springframework.shell</groupId> 
    <artifactId>spring-shell-starter</artifactId> 
    <version>3.3.3</version> 
</dependency> 

Application.properties:
    spring.shell.script.enabled=true 
spring.shell.interactive.enabled=true 

FileSystem.java:
@Service 
public class FileSystem { 
     
   private final Path path = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home")).resolve("fs"); 
    //boolean file = new File(path).mkdir(); 
    File file = new File(path.toString()); 
     
   public FileSystem() { 
 
        if(!Files.exists(this.path)){ 
            this.file.mkdir(); 
            System.out.println("Folder "+ path + " created."); 
 
        }else { 
            System.out.println(("Folder " + path + " already exists.")); 
        } 
        System.out.println(freeDiscSpace()); 
    } 
    public String freeDiscSpace(){ 
        long freeSpace = file.getFreeSpace(); 
        return "There is a total of " + String.valueOf(freeSpace) + " bytes of free space in " + path + "."; 
    } 
} 

FsCommands.java:
@ShellComponent 
public class FsCommands { 
 
    private final FileSystem fs; 
    public FsCommands(FileSystem fs){ 
        this.fs = fs; 
    } 
    @ShellMethod("Display required free disk space") 
    public long minimumFreeDiskSpace(){ 
        return 1_000_000; 
    } 
    @ShellMethod("Lowercase") 
    public String toLowercase(String input){ 
        return input.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT); 
    } 
    @ShellMethod("Display free disk space") 
    public String freeDiskSpace(){ 
        return String.valueOf(fs.freeDiscSpace()); 
    } 
} 

applicationproperties
    spring.application.name=einletztesmal

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/einletztesmal;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=test
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.shell.interactive.enabled=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.sql.init.mode=always

    enter code here


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

You made an Error in your application.properties you have to save it in a file to make it permanently saved. The file of the h2 DB will appear in your C:User:[user] directory.
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/testprojektDB;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=test
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.shell.interactive.enabled=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.sql.init.mode=always


Paging, Sort and Filtering
StudentService:
public Page<Student> getStudentsWithFilters(String firstname, String lastname, Integer age, Pageable pageable) {
    Specification<Student> spec = Specification.where(null);

    if (firstname != null && !firstname.isEmpty()) {
        spec = spec.and(StudentSpecification.firstnameContains(firstname));
    }

    if (lastname != null && !lastname.isEmpty()) {
        spec = spec.and(StudentSpecification.lastnameContains(lastname));
    }

    if (age != null) {
        spec = spec.and(StudentSpecification.ageEquals(age));
    }

    return studentRepository.findAll(spec, pageable);
}

StudentController:
// Beispiel-URL:
// http://localhost:8080/students/search?firstname=Armin&lastname=Dilic&age=18&page=0&size=10&sort=lastname,asc
@GetMapping("/search")
public Page<Student> getStudents(
        @RequestParam(required = false) String firstname,
        @RequestParam(required = false) String lastname,
        @RequestParam(required = false) Integer age,
        @PageableDefault(size = 10) Pageable pageable) {
    return studentService.getStudentsWithFilters(firstname, lastname, age, pageable);
}

StudentSpecification
public class StudentSpecification {

public static Specification<Student> firstnameContains(String firstname) {
    return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) ->
            criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("firstname"), "%" + firstname + "%");
}

public static Specification<Student> lastnameContains(String lastname) {
    return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) ->
            criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("lastname"), "%" + lastname + "%");
}

public static Specification<Student> ageEquals(Integer age) {
    return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) ->
            criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("age"), age);
}

}
